# ffmpeg convert video file with 8 audio channels to multichannel wav

Tags: ffmpeg, mapping, wav, channel

> on run {input, parameters}
>      tell application "Terminal"
>          activate
>          set filesString to ""
>          repeat with file_ in input
>              set filesString to filesString & " " & quoted form of (POSIX path >of file_)
>          end repeat
>         do script "for f in" & filesString & "; do
>   ~/Documents/ffmpeg/ffmpeg -i \"$f\" -acodec pcm_s16le \"${f%.*}.wav\"
>   done"
>      end tell
>      return input
>   end run

I wrote an applescript to add a right-click service in OS X, but this only takes the first channel and creates a mono wav file. How can i create a multichannel wav to accommodate 8 mono tracks?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## amerge

One method is to use the [amerge filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#amerge):

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1][0:a:2][0:a:3][0:a:4][0:a:5][0:a:6][0:a:7]amerge=inputs=8" output.wav
```

## join

Another method is to use the [join filter](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#join):

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "[0:a:0][0:a:1][0:a:2][0:a:3][0:a:4][0:a:5][0:a:6][0:a:7]join=inputs=8:channel_layout=7.1" output.wav
```

*join* has the advantage over *amerge* of allowing you to have more control over which streams go where in output channel layout:

```
ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex "join=inputs=8:channel_layout=7.1:map=0.0-FL|1.0-FR|2.0-FC|3.0-LFE|4.0-BL|5.0-BR|6.0-SL|7.0-SR" output.wav
```

#### Notes

- `[0:a:5]` refers to the 4th audio stream of input number 0 (the first and only input in this example).
- You can omit the filter input labels (`[0:a:0][0:a:1][0:a:2]`, etc) if you know you can trust the default stream selection behavior.
- You can see a list of supported channel layouts with `ffmpeg -layouts`.

Comment: the GreatLordNeckbeard, i've read alot about you on various forums :-) so this works on a single file in Terminal but my Applescript errors out for some reason. not entirely sure why...looking into it.

Comment: and to be honest, i would settle for it taking the first two tracks and maintaining that in the wav (it only takes the first with the usage in my original post). i've had a lot of trouble with audio mapping and Applescript and i'm not sure why. ultimately want to package this up and send out to our field teams that don't have QT or an NLE installed so they can create wavs off of raw camera footage quickly and easily w/ little knowledge of Media Encoder and other platforms so they can send away to an automated transcription service.

Comment: @imgoingtoshabooms Sorry, but I know nothing about Applescript. As for just stereo using two streams as input, a simple command could look something like `ffmpeg -i input -filter_complex join=inputs=2 output.wav`, but I would probably add the input labels for the filter for more defined behavior like in the answer examples.